# Efficiency of multicolumn indexes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain, multiple-columns

If I have a MyISAM table with a 3-column index, something like

```
create table t (
  a int,
  b int,
  c int,
  index abc (a, b, c)
) engine=MyISAM;
```

the question is, can the following query fully utilize the index:

```
select * from t where a=1 and c=2;
```

in other words, considering that an index is a b-tree, can MySQL skip the column in the middle and still do a quick search on first and last columns?

EXPLAIN does seem to be showing that the index will be used, however, the Extra says: `Using where; Using index` and I have no idea what this really means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "no".

The MySQL documentation is quite clear on how indexes are used:

*If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).*  (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html.)

What happens is that the index gets used for "a=1".  All records that match are loaded, to see if "c=2" is true.  The filter ends up using a combination of indexes and explicit record filtering.

By the way, if you want to handle all combinations of two columns, you need several indexes:

- (a, b, c)
- (b, a, c)
- (c, b, a)

Answer (score 0):

> Even if you are using an index for all parts of a WHERE clause, you
>   may see Using where if the column can be NULL.

As per `MySQL` documentation, the above statement clarifies that the column in your table could be null and hence it says `using where` as well though it has covering index for fields in where clause.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information

Comment: Thanks, but no, in my case none of the columns can be NULL. So looks like `using where` simply means it can't fully use my index?